# remove all decimal points and put a %

Tags: c#

I want to remove all the decimal points from a decimal value and add a '%' at the end.
I am trying with the following code.

```
<%:string.Format("{0:0}",i.discount) %>
```

this makes 10.0000 to 10. 
But is there any way that i can put a '%' after 10??

EDIT:
I am showing data in a table. Some rows have discount value and some rows does not.
SO my query returns null or the discount value.

I only want to show the (%) in those row, that have discount value. I do not want to show only (%) in those rows that does not have any discount value.

Hope it explains the question better.

Comment: How do you determine which rows have a discount? What is `i.discount` for those rows?

Comment: well..i.discount returns the discount value.

Comment: And... if there is no discount?

Comment: So `i.discount` is a `decimal?` (nullable decimal)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
<%:i.discount.ToString("P0") %>
```

Alternatively,

```
<%:string.Format("{0:P0}", i.discount) %>
```

Note that this multiplies the number by 100, making 10.00 into 1000%; this may not be what you want.

**EDIT**: Since you indicate in your comment that this is *not* what you want, try one of the following:

```
<%:(i.discount / 100.0).ToString("P0") %>
<%:string.Format("{0:P0}", i.discount / 100.0) %>
```

These should leave the value blank if `i.discount` is null.

For formatting a single numeric value, `ToString` is marginally more efficient than `string.Format`, because `string.Format` has a bunch of overhead to parse the format string out of the curly braces and then pass it to `ToString`.

Comment: this returns 1.0000 %...this is not i want. I want 10%

Comment: @kandroid then how about `<%:(i.discount / 100.0).ToString("P0") %>`?  This will prevent the problem of showing a % symbol when the discount is null.

Comment: I think <%:string.Format("{0:P0}", i.discount/100) %> this solves the problem. cheers

Answer (score 4):

Using the [standard format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx):

```
<%:(i.discount / 100).ToString("P0") %>
```

You can simply add the `%` to the end of the string:

```
<%:string.Format("{0:0}%",i.discount) %>
```

Alternatively, after the string, embedded in the markup:

```
<%:string.Format("{0:0}",i.discount) %>%
```

Comment: ok The problem is i am showing data in a table. some row has discount and some row does not. Those who do not have any discount i have only (%) in those rows. Did you get my point??

Comment: @kandroid- Sure. Shame you didn't put that in the question. Rather important. How do you know that a row doesn't have a discount?

Answer (score 1):

Add the `%` to your format string.

```
<%:string.Format("{0:0}%",i.discount) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this;

```
<%:string.Format("{0:0}%",(int)i.discount) %>
```

You could also use `Math.Floor`, `Math.Round` or `Math.Ceil` for better rounding.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the percent formatters:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx